# Simplifying the body of a pure function

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pure-function

After solving a differential equation I obtain a pure function which I wish to simplify.

I am able to simplify the corresponding **expression**

```
expr = Cos[x] Cot[g] / Sqrt[-Cos[a]^2 Cot[g]^2 + Sin[a]^2]
```

according to the relationship `k == Sin[a] / Cos[g]` using a replacement followed by simplification with assumptions:

```
expr /. a -> ArcSin[k Cos[g]] // FullSimplify[#, 0 < g < Pi/2] &
(* Cos[x] / Sqrt[-1 + k^2] *) (* hooray *)
```

However if I attempt the same thing with the **pure function** (which is the output of some `DSolve` command)

```
fun = Function[{x}, Cos[x] Cot[g] / Sqrt[-Cos[a]^2 Cot[g]^2 + Sin[a]^2]]
```

it doesn't work:

```
fun  /. a -> ArcSin[k Cos[g]] // FullSimplify[#, 0 < g < Pi/2] &
(* Function[{x}, Cos[x] Cot[g] / Sqrt[-Cos[ArcSin[k Cos[g]]]^2 Cot[g]^2 + Sin[ArcSin[k Cos[g]]]^2]] *)
```

How do I get the body of the pure function to simplify in the same way as it does with the expression? (i.e. desired output is `Function[{x}, Cos[x] / Sqrt[-1 + k^2]]` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fun = Function[{x}, Cos[x] Cot[g]/Sqrt[-Cos[a]^2 Cot[g]^2 + Sin[a]^2]];

fun[[2]] = 
  FullSimplify[fun[[2]] /. a -> ArcSin[k Cos[g]], 0 < g < Pi/2];

fun
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fun /. {
 Verbatim[Function][args_,expr_]:> 
  Function[args, Evaluate@FullSimplify[expr/. a -> ArcSin[k Cos[g]], 0 < g < Pi/2 ]]
 }
```

Of course you can do this with any command you want to apply to the pure function.

Comment: I think the body `FullSimplify[`...`]` needs `// Evaluate`; otherwise good.

Answer (score 1):

```
simp = FullSimplify[#, 0 < g < Pi/2] &;
rule = a -> ArcSin[k Cos[g]];
(*Method 1*)
Function[x, #] &@simp[fun@x /. rule]
(*Method 2*)
Replace[fun /. rule, expr_ :> RuleCondition@simp@expr, {1}]
(*Method 3*)
fun /. f : Function :> Hold@f /. rule // simp // ReleaseHold
(*Method 4*)
simp[fun /. Function -> func /. rule] /. func -> Function
```